# Сервер на nodejs вместо данных отдаёт их длину

Tags: node.js

Задача: 
Стучимся на сервер nodejs (например так: curl 127.0.0.1:8888), тот, в свою очередь, стучится на скрипт. Полученный от скрипта ответ сервер отдаёт обратно.
В моём случае скрипт отвечает:

```
echo "Auth: 1";
```

Мне ответ приходит в виде двух строк:

```
7
Auth
```

Вот код:

```
var http = require("http");
var app = http.createServer(function(request, response)
{
  console.log ("Success!");
  console.log("Request URL: "+request.url);
  response.writeHead(200);
  var scriptRequest = http.request(
                {
                    hostname: "test.master12.ru",
                    port: 80,
                    path: "http://test.master12.ru/index.php",
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: request.headers || {}
                });
  scriptRequest.on("response", function (scriptResponse)
                {
                    var headers = scriptResponse.headers;
                    response.writeHead(200, headers);
                    scriptResponse.setEncoding('utf8');
                    scriptResponse.on("data", function (data)
                                        {
                                           console.log("Remote script response: "+data);
                                           response.write(data);
                                        });
                    scriptResponse.on("close", function()
                                        {
                                           response.writeHead(scriptResponse.statusCode);
                                           response.end();
                                        });
                    scriptResponse.on("error", function (err)
                                        {
                                           console.log("Error:"+err);
                                           response.end();
                                        });
                    scriptResponse.on("end", function ()
                                        {
                                           console.log("End script response");
                                           response.writeHead(scriptResponse.statusCode);
                                           response.end();
                                        });
                });

request.on("data", function (data)
        {
            console.log("Client request:"+data);
            scriptRequest.write(data);
        });
request.on("end", function ()
        {
            console.log("End client request.");
            scriptRequest.end();
        });
 });
app.listen(8888, "127.0.0.1");
```

То есть сервер мне отдаёт длину ответа и первые 4 символа. При этом в консоль выводит всё верно.

Comment: Кажется вам сервер отвечает в Chunked-формате.

Comment: А чем вас `scriptResponse.pipe(response)` не устроил?

Comment: @Alexey Ten, поменял в 6-й строке `response.writeHead(200);` на `response.writeHead(200, {'Transfer-Encoding' : ''});` и всё заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: @Dmitriy Simushev, с node.js я ещё только знакомлюсь, знаю мало. Обязательно попробую решить эту же задачу с `*.pipe`. Спасибо.